# Java - Generating Random Numbers in java between 0.5 and 6.28

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random number in a range with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-number-in-a-range-with-java)

My code is generating random numbers between 0 and 1.
I need to generate a random number between 0.5 and 6.28.

My current Code:

```
public class Random_Number_Generator
{
    double randomGenerator()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        double num = generator.nextDouble();

        return num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
double num = generator.nextDouble()*(6.28-0.5) + 0.5;
```

As [nextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) returns a number in `[0, 1[`, you generally have to do

```
double num = generator.nextDouble()*(max-min) + min;
```

when you want a number in `[min, max[`.

Comment: can you please explain how this works ?

Also, if i want to generate between 0 & 0.5...what would it be ?

Comment: nextDouble() returns a double between 0 and 1. If you want a double between 0 and 0.5, you do `generator.nextDouble()*0.5`.

Comment: your number is between 0 and 1, so (6.28-0.5 = 5.78) * number is between 0 and 5.78. and that + 0.5 is between 0.5 and 6.28.

Comment: so according to this...if i use 

double num = generator.nextDouble()*(0.5-0);

it would generate random numbers between 0 and 0.5

Comment: So will `generator.nextDouble()/2;`